# Prove that $\mathbb{F}^{\infty}$ is infinite-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

I am pretty sure the general idea of my proof is correct, but I am not sure if it is coherent. For example, is something like $i \in I$ , which I mean by for any number $i$ in the index ($I$), common enough notation or is there a better way to state it?

---

Suppose the span($\mathbb{F}^{\infty}) = \{e_1, e_2, \dots , e_n\}$. Then for any vector $v \in \mathbb{F}^{\infty}$, 
$$v = a_1e_1,  + \dots + a_me_m,~ i \in I,~ a_i \in \mathbb{R}, m > n$$

Then clearly $v$ is not a linear combination of span($\mathbb{F}^{\infty})$ and contradicts the fact that a spanning set must be finite. Thus $\mathbb{F}^{\infty}$ is not finite and is therefore infinite-dimensional.

Comment: Who is $m$? Why do you talk about the span of $\mathbb{F}^{\infty}$? (Isn't that a vector space? What is the span of a vector space? Do you mean $\mathbb{F}^{\infty}=\mathrm{span}(\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\})$?\). I would say that this isn't very good, because all you are doing is showing that no initial subset of the $e_i$ will be a basis, but you would still need to argue that **no finite set of vectors** can span. Better would be to show that you have linearly independent subsets of arbitrarily large (finite) size.

Comment: If you want to use your idea: show that the subspace of sequences with finitely many nonzero components is infinitely dimensional.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so because a linearly independent subspace can be extended to the basis of the vector space, we can keep extending the subspace to an indefinitely large size?

Comment: Subspaces are never linearly independent. You need to stop confusing sets and subspaces.

Comment: @EvanKim the set only get larger if it is not maximal. Obviously you can not assume $\mathbb^\infty$ is infinitely dimensional to show it is infinitely dimensional...

Comment: We know that if $S$ is a spanning set and $T$ is a linearly independent set, then $T$ has at most as many elements as $S$/$S$ has at least as many elements as $T$. If you have a linearly independent set of size $k$, then no basis can have fewer than $k$ elements. In particular, if for every positive integer $k$ you have a linearly independent set of size $k$, then no basis can have $m$ elements for *any* positive integer $m$. So there can be no finite basis.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am not sure if I completely follow your last line with $k$ and $m$, is $k > m$?

Comment: They are arbitrary integers. If for any integer $k$ you can find a linearly independent set with $k$ elements, and you have a set with $m$ elements, then the set cannot span (because you can find a linearly independent set with $m+1$ elements, and any spanning set always has more elements than any linearly independent set).

Comment: So you are saying that since we can add an infinite amount of basis vectors to any linearly independent set $T$, then the spanning set $S$ will never be able to have at least as many elements as $T$?

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. I am saying exactly what I said: if you have *any* spanning set $S$, and *any* linearly independent set $T$, then we know that $S$ has at least as many elements as $T$ does. This is a consequence of the so-called replacement theorem, and it is a key ingredient in showing that the dimension of a (finite dimensional) vector spaces is well-defined.

Comment: So...you are saying then that for any spanning set $S$, we can find a linearly independent set that is larger than $S$ in this vector space?

Comment: Always find a larger linearly independent set*

Comment: No. In a vector space $V$ (**any** vector space) we can **never** find a linearly independent set that has more elements than a given spanning set. You are utterly lost here.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think $\mathbb{F}$ is a field and you're considering:
$$
\mathbb{F}^\infty = \{(x_1,x_2,...): x_i \in \mathbb{F}\}
$$
Suppose that $\dim(\mathbb{F^\infty})<+\infty$. Then, exists $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dim(\mathbb{F^\infty})< n$, $\forall n> n_0$. However, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we considering $T_n: \mathbb{F}^\infty \to \mathbb{F}^n$ defined by:
$$
T_n(x_1,x_2,...) = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)
$$
Clearly, $T_n$ is a linear transformation and $T_n$ is surjective and not injective. Then, we obtain:
$$
\dim(F^\infty) > n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
Thus obtaining a contradiction, therefore $\dim(\mathbb{F^\infty}) = +\infty$. 
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \blacksquare$

Comment: yea but I thought $T_n$ had to be bijective linear transformation

Comment: No. For example, let $x = (1,0,0,...)$ and $y=(1,0,1,0,...)$. Then:
$T_2(x) = T_2(y) = (1,0)$, but $x\neq y$.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't work.

Things to address:

1) What is $I$?

2) 'Clearly $v$ is not a linear combination...' This is not clear. In fact it's the opposite: you have written down $v$ as a linear combination of the spanning set, and 
so there is no contradiction.

Try writing down the definition of $\mathbb{F}^\infty$

Comment: I forgot to add that $m > n$. The idea was to show that there is a linear combination of $m$ vectors that is not in the span(S), but in $\mathbb{F}^{\infty}$

Comment: In this case, you have only defined $e_j$ for $j \leq n$. For $n < j \leq m$, what is $e_j$?